# Defining a class instead of attribute

Tags: jquery

How could I properly edit the below line to include a specific class, as opposed to the href attribute?

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "include a specific class" exactly? Please add more detail or ideally, an example.

Comment: What class are you trying to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a.className").attr("href");
```

if you use

```
 .attr("href");
```

it will not match the `href` rather it will return the href of the matched `a` tags

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
var activeTab = $(this).find('.your_class').attr("href");
```

or you may try `closest()` like;

```
var activeTab = $(this).closest('tr').find('.your_class').attr("href");
//i took <tr> as a child in this example just for a demo. You may change it according to your HTML structure
```

or you may try `children` like;

```
var activeTab = $(this).children('.your_class').attr("href");
```

Hope this helps.